# Probability of getting consecutive heads in $100$ coin tosses if$ P(H) = 0.04$ and $P(T) = 0.96$

Tags: probability, statistics

If there is an uneven coin where heads show up $4\text{%}$ of the time and tails show up $96\text{%}$ of the time, what is the probability of seeing consecutive heads in $100$ coin tosses?

Comment: Going off of my gut I feel like it would be $1-(1-0.04^2)^99$

Comment: What is the probability that you get a heads once - this is $0.04$. What about twice - this is $0.04\times 0.04=0.04^2$. Do you see how to get this for 100 times?

Comment: @Dave notice how the 0.04 in my reply is squared.

Comment: @connorlane Your expression is about $0.14660$  but I suspect that $0.14162$ is closer - there is not independence between overlapping pairs.  Try with $3$ tosses, where your method gives $\frac{1249}{5^8}=0.00319744$ while I think the actual figure is $\frac{49}{5^6}=0.003136$

Comment: @connorlane My comment was directed at the OP. However, you comment is confusing to me also: I don't see how you got this as the answer.

Comment: @syndee Do you want the probability of getting heads twice in a row at least once within 100 tosses, or do you want the probability that all 100 tosses are heads?

Comment: ignoring boundary conditions, if you looked at the complementary event -- i.e. at an point in time if you haven't had a run of 2 heads then your 'trailing view' is the last coin toss was $T$ or the last two tosses were $HT$ which are mutually exclusive events.  This allows for modelling a recurrence with this matrix $\displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}\frac{24}{25} & \frac{24}{625}\\1 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$.  Diagonalizing gets the closed form solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, the probability of getting at least two consecutive heads is $14.1620049600103\%$.

To find this value, let define the variable $X$ which is the beginning of the first two consecutive heads. E.g. if $X=6$, there are no two consecutive heads before the sixth throw, the fifth throw need to be tail, the sixth and seventh throw are heads. The rest doesn't matter.

The first three cases are straightforward. $X=1$, getting heads on the first two throw.
$$P(X=1)=(0.04)(0.04)$$
$X=2$, we need $THH$
$$P(X=2)=(0.96)(0.04)(0.04)$$
$X=3$, we have $?THH$ ( first throw doesn't matter).
$$P(X=3)=(1)(0.96)(0.04)(0.04)$$
Starting from $X=4$, we need to make sure there are no consecutive heads before.
$$P(X=4)=\left(1-\sum_{k=1}^1P(X=k)\right)(0.96)(0.04)(0.04)$$
Generaly, 
$$P(X=n)=\left(1-\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}P(X=k)\right)(0.96)(0.04)(0.04)$$
We want to know the sum up to $X=99$.
Using a spread sheet, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{99}P(X=n)=14.1620049600103\%$$
Thanks to @Henry for a closed form of this number
$$1-\left(\frac12-\frac{13\sqrt{42}}{168}\right)\left(\frac{12-\sqrt{168}}{25}\right)^{100}-\left(\frac12+\frac{13\sqrt{42}}{168}\right)\left(\frac{12+\sqrt{168}}{25}\right)^{100}$$

Comment: +1 though I suspect there is may be closed form for this sum involving powers of $1, \frac1{25}, \frac{12}{25}\pm\frac{\sqrt{168}}{25}$

Comment: Try $1-\frac{25}{336}(7-\sqrt{42})\left(\frac{12-\sqrt{168}}{25}\right)^{100} -\frac{25}{336}(7+\sqrt{42})\left(\frac{12+\sqrt{168}}{25}\right)^{100}$

Comment: @Henry thanks. There was a small mistake in my answer. Seem like I forgot to add the last case. I now have the same value you gave in a comment of the original post. I also added your formula for the closed form.

Comment: Yor are welcome.  Strangely, I had been persuaded by your previous answer

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the probability $q_n$ of *not* getting consecutive heads in $n$ coin tosses, then the last toss must either have been a tail, or must have been a head preceded by a tail, so you can say $$q_n=0.96 q_{n-1} +(0.04 \times 0.96) q_{n-2}$$ and clearly you start with $q_0=q_1=1$.

You can either cycle through the recurrence or you can solve the generating function.  Either way, the answer to this specific question is $$1-q_{100} \approx 1- 0.85838 \approx 0.14162.$$

Comment: I actually found this response backwards from the closed-form solution in Alain Remillard's response to a simpler generating function than the one I had used for that solution, and then looked for a justification for the simpler form*